# Eclipse plugin: How to specify what launch configurations appear in a project's properties?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I have an Eclipse plugin with a launch delegate, a launch shortcut (which has enablement set to appear when a project has a certain nature), and a launch configuration tab group. They all work just as I want them to, except for one fact. When you go into a project's properties, in "Run/Debug Settings", there's a list of configurations that could apply to this project. The problem is, when it's of my project nature, the list it shows consists of ALL the configurations of my type.

My launch configurations specify what project they apply to, by storing it in a custom attribute, but there's no way for Eclipse to know this, which begs the question: How do you filter what configurations appear in "Run/Debug Settings"? The Eclipse documentation is seemingly silent on this topic.

Comment: The list in the table comes from the `getApplicableLaunchConfigurations` method of `org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.launchConfigurations.LaunchConfigurationManager`. You are probably going to have to read the source of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With major thanks to greg-449, I have a solution. The problem was that the launch configuration needed to define a resource mapping. Every launch configuration has a list of resources that "belong" to the configuration, and the "Run/Debug Settings" menu only shows launch configurations that have that resource as a mapping. If there is no mapping in the launch configuration, it is assumed to be applicable to all resources.

In my custom `ILaunchConfigurationTabGroup`, I failed to add any resource mappings based on the project. All it took was the addition of this line to `performApply`:

```
configuration.setMappedResources(new IResource[] {project});
```

Where `project` is whatever resources you want the launch config to appear in.